# How to return JSONObject in Spring without 406 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am learning to use Spring, using Spring-boot.

I want to return a JSONObject from a Controller but it always return 406.

I imported a  ***org.json.JSONObject;*** to create a JSONObject.

Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody   
public Object testJsonCall(){
    JSONObject reply = new JSONObject();
    reply.put("status","success");
    reply.put("foo", "bar");
    return reply;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does the client accept JSON back? The Accept header may indicate it doesn't, hence Spring returns HTTP 406, as it cannot fulfill the request with the json content. OR, you need org.codehaus.jackson to support returning non-String values. We need more info on your project.

Comment: In the client request, I added header Content-Type for application/json.

And I also included jackson-core-asl and jackson-mapper-asl in the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. Now I've found a solution.

Initially, I tried adding jackson-core and jackson-core-asl but it didn't make it to work.
Wierdly, I've just added toString to the return, it is working !

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody   
public Object testJsonCall(){
    JSONObject reply = new JSONObject();
    reply.put("status","success");
    reply.put("foo", "bar");
    return reply.toString();  //here I added toString()
}
```

Comment: As a general recommendation, try not to use JSONObject directly when working with Spring and instead take advantage of the Jackson object mapping that's built-in with Spring Boot. In this case you could create a `Reply` class with `status` and `foo` fields. Then you can simply `return new Reply("success", "bar");` and update your method signature to `public Reply testJsonCall()`. Spring Boot uses Jackson to automatically convert that to JSON in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following jars to pom.xml.

```
<dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId> <version>2.4.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> <version>2.4.1.1</version> </dependency>

<dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId> <version>1.9.13</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId> <version>1.9.13</version> </dependency>
```